# capacitive leakage current

Tags: current-transformer

The question and answer is:

[image]

Why didn't he use the secondary voltage?

I mean it should be

a = Is / Ip = 5 / 2000 = 1 / 400

secondary voltage = 115 * 400 = 46 MV

Thus, leakage current = 46 MV / 10.6 MΩ = 4.33 A

Source:

OBJECTIVE ELECTRICAL TECHNOLOGY

For the Students of UPSC (Engg. Services); IAS (Engg. Group); B.Sc. Engg.; Diploma and Other Competitive Courses.

(Over 3500 Objective Questions with Hints) V.K. MEHTA, ROHIT MEHTA

S. CHAND & COMPANY LTD.

ISBN : 81-219-2097-3, 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're talking about a CT here and, CTs have a burden resistor on the output that limits the secondary voltage to a few volts. You have calculated 46 MV and that is a ridiculous voltage to have on a CT output. The whole point of this exercise is thinking about the capacitance from the 115 kV line to neutral (0 volts) and calculating the current that flows through 250 pF.

It has nothing to do with the CT's primary voltage (much less than a small fraction of a volt) nor anything to do with the output secondary voltage (a few volts maximum).